# Code to append table into div in html via jQuery - jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile, html-table

I'm trying to append html code via Jquery ajax.

I have a html form (jQuery mobile) and send data to PHP file when hitting submit button via JQuery Ajax.

PHP file, send back JSON data like this:

```
{"employee":[{"Name":"Mario","Surname":"K","ID":"234"}, {"Name":"Helen","Surname":"Smith","ID":"546"]}
```

I want to create a table on "your-table" div, that includes the JSON data. 
This is my code:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addSubmit").click(function(){
      var postData = $("#addForm").serialize();
      var action = "add";
      $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:"http://10.0.2.2/phpAndAjax/index-handler.php",
            crossDomain : true,
            data: {postData: postData, action: action},
            success: function() {

                var action = "show";
                 $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:"http://10.0.2.2/phpAndAjax/index-handler.php",
                    crossDomain : true,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {action: action},
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));

                        $('#your-table').append('<table>');
                        $('#your-table').append('<tr>');
                            $('#your-table').append('<th> Name </th>');
                            $('#your-table').append('<th> Surname </th>');
                            $('#your-table').append('<th> ID </th>');
                            $('#your-table').append('<th> E-mail </th>');
                        $('#your-table').append('</tr>');

                              $.each(data, function(i, item) {

                                    var Name=item.name;
                                    $('#your-table').append('<tr>');
                                    $('#your-table').append('<th>'+Name+'</th>');
                                    $('#your-table').append('</tr>');

                              });
                            $('#your-table').append('</table>');
                            }
                     });
                }
          });
      });
 });
</script>

</head>
<body>


                    <!--Main page -->
<div data-role="page" id="main" >
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Employee management system</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <br>
        <form id="select_form" method="POST">
            <p>
                <label id="action">Please, select one of the following</label> <br>
                <br> 
                <a href="#searchEmployee" data-role="button">Search an employee 
                    (Edit and Delete)</a> 
                <a href="#addEmployee" data-role="button">Add Employee</a>
            </p>
        </form>
        <div id="your-table"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Add employee page -->
<div data-role="page" id="addEmployee">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h2>Add an employee</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form id="addForm" method="post">
            <p>
                <label for="name">Firstname</label> 
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="required" /> <br>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="surname">Lastname</label> <input id="surname"
                    name="surname" type="text" class="required" /> <br>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="id">ID</label> 
                <input id="id" name="id" type="text" class="required"  /> <br>
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="addSubmit" value="Add employee"> 
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script it's alerting right, but the table its not created. I tried something easier like to add just a paragraph but neither works.

Any help it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery expects argument for `append` to be whole DOM element. Not just a part of it.

For example: `<table>` is missing close tag. Same with `<tr>`, and also it is being appended to `$('#your-table')` (not inside table, but next to it as sibling element), but you would want it to be appended to `$('#your-table table')`.

Easiest way for you to make it work would be prepare whole table HTML structure and append it one go. Like this:

```
var tableHtml = '<table>';
tableHtml += '<tr>';
tableHtml += '<th> Name </th>';
tableHtml += '<th> Surname </th>';
tableHtml += '<th> ID </th>';
...
tableHtml += '</table>';
$('#your-table').append(tableHtml);
```

Comment: Is there any specific jquery library that i have to add? Because I tried this but nothing happens.

Comment: If you say that your `alert()` works, then you have needed jQuery library already. (because Ajax call trough `jQuery.ajax()` was successful)

Try putting `$('#your-table').append("<table><tr><td>It works!</td></tr></table>");` right after your `alert()`.

If this works, then try looking at HTML content produced in `tableHtml` and make sure it's valid.

Comment: Still not working. 
The #addSubmit button which is firing the jquery ajax is not in #main (where i want to display the table). It is in page #addEmployee. 
Does this causing any problem? 
I added the code in the html now.

Comment: I was right...The problem wasn't on the code for the table but on the #main page load...